# how to immediately update displayed textbox before a long loop

Tags: c#, .net

My event handler UIButton440_TouchUpInside( UIButton sender ) updates my TextBox.Text then does a long loop, then returns.  But Textbox doesn't update until after return.

How can I display the updated TextBox immediately?

(Like vb.net does with application.doEvents)

Comment: You have any code for this?  Maybe rung this long loop in a task?

Comment: the use of break; might be handy

Comment: Can you not use notifypropertychanged ?

Answer (score 3):

You can try firing a thread to do your long loop. I usually like using workers for that, something like this:

```
        txt.Text = "abc";
        BackgroundWorker worker = new BackgroundWorker();

        worker.DoWork += (o, ea) =>
        {
            //Long loop
        };
        worker.RunWorkerCompleted += (o, ea) =>
        {
            //Do something when the loop ends
        };
        worker.RunWorkerAsync();
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're using Windows Forms, you can call the `Update` method on the `TextBox` to force a refresh.

```
yourTextBox.Update();
```

Comment: @MikeH If the loop is on the main thread, the Update call wouldn't have any affect.  Calling Update isn't the bad practice.  Solving the issue by calling DoEvents would be the bad practice.

Comment: @LarsTech Looks like I've forgotten the specifics forcing updates on the GUI thread (since I endeavor not to do it) .  I retract my comments.

Comment: `it's almost 2019 and the guy is still doing Windows Forms... Do you think he's worried about bad practices`  As a WinForms programmer, you have to probably be more aware of bad practices then newer platforms in order to have maintainable code.  Lots of legacy code out there that don't have any reasonable upgrade paths to newer platforms.